# Get list of dependent objects via SQL query or function

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have two tables. One is for Task and second is dependency table for the tasks.
I want a query to give me all the tasks (recursively) based on a particular id.

I have two tables. One is for Task

```
ID  TASK  
1   Abc  
2   Def  
3   Ghi  
4   Jkl  
5   Mno  
6   Pqr
```

The second one is for getting dependent tasks

```
ID  DEPENDENT_ON  
2   1  
3   1  
4   2  
4   6  
5   2  
6   5
```

Is it possible to write a sql query to get a list of all the tasks (recursive) which are dependent on a particular task.

Example.
I want to check all tasks dependent on ID=1. 
Expected output (which is 2 and 3):

```
2.Def
3.Ghi
```

Furthermore query should also give output of these two dependent tasks and so on.
Final output should be:

```
2.Def -- level one
3.Ghi -- level one 
4.Jkl -- Dependent on task 2  
5.Mno -- Dependent on task 2 
6.Pqr -- Dependent on task 5
```

Formatting is not important. Just output is required

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple recursive query in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50123407/simple-recursive-query-in-oracle)

Comment: As explained I need to join two tables and then do a recursive search.
I am unable to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to join two tables and then do a recursive search.

You must OUTER JOIN the second table (which you didn't name, so I have called it TASK_TREE) through DEPENDENT_ON to the parent ID. Outer join because task 1 is the top of the tree and depends on no task. Then use Oracle's hierarchical query syntax to walk the tree:

```
select t.id, t.task, tt.dependent_on, level
from tasks t
     left outer join task_tree tt on tt.id = t.id
connect by prior t.id = tt.dependent_on 
start with t.id = 1
/
```

I have included the `level` so you can see how the tree unfurls. The Oracle SQL documentation covers hierarchical queries in depth. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries003.htm#SQLRF52315). If you don't want to use Oracle's proprietary hierarchical syntax, from 11gR2 Oracle supported recursive WITH clause. [Find out more](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/recursive-subquery-factoring-11gr2).

Incidentally, your posted data contains a error. Task 4 depends on both 2 and 6. Hierarchies must have child nodes which depend on a single parent node. Otherwise you'll get all sorts of weird results.

Comment: Thanks for this, but data doesn't contain error, single task might be dependent on one or more task.
This is because data required by 4 is populated by 2 and 6.

Comment: Then, as I say, hierarchical queries will contain odd results. Task 4 will appear multiple times in the result set.