# Having a node at level N

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write the code by Having a node at level N (for example 3) of the tree, find all members up to level M (for example 6).How can I write this code? what is the best idea for this problem?
I am new in oracle , please explain me and help me for resolve this problem .

Comment: Just as you would normally recurse a tree, but limit it to 3 levels of recursion/connection.  *(Don't treat it as starting at level N, your start point is always Level 0, then you stop at Level 6-3, which is 3)*  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50125911/53341

Comment: @MatBailie thanks for replying but I can not write this code , please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE tree (
    node_id     INT,
    parent_id   INT
)
```

```
INSERT INTO
  tree
          SELECT    1, NULL FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT    2,    1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT    3,    1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT    4,    2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT    5,    2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT    6,    3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT    7,    3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT    8,    4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT    9,    4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT   10,    5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT   11,    5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT   12,    6 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT   13,    6 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT   14,    7 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT   15,    7 FROM DUAL
```

```
15 rows affected
```

```
SELECT
  node_id, parent_id, level
FROM
  tree
WHERE
  level < 3
CONNECT BY
  PRIOR node_id = parent_id
START WITH
  parent_id = 3
ORDER BY
  level, node_id
```

| NODE_ID | PARENT_ID | LEVEL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 3 | 1 |
| 7 | 3 | 1 |
| 12 | 6 | 2 |
| 13 | 6 | 2 |
| 14 | 7 | 2 |
| 15 | 7 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_oyglXji)